# Don't set wm_class of "Navigator" when starting Firefox

Tags: firefox, desktop, application

I'm starting Firefox as follows:

```
/usr/bin/firefox --no-remote -P Fastmail --class "FastmailFF"
```

The ultimate goal is to figure out a command to put in a .desktop file which will have it's own icon and exist separately to the normal browser.

The above gets grouped under the current Firefox icon.

When I inspect the window using `xprop WM_CLASS` command, I get the following back for the above:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "FastmailFF"
```

and the following for the main Firefox:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "firefox"
```

So I figure the common "Navigator" string is causing the grouping.

Is there a way to prevent `Navigator` getting added upon startup?

It looks like firefox is installed via a snap:

```
Version: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
```

I'm running gnome 42.5 and wayland

Answer (score 0):

**Update (2023-07-07)**: Removing the `-no-remote` CLI option avoids the *Firefox is already running, but is not responding* error.

For me (using Wayland and Gnome 43 on Fedora 37), the catch was to use `--name FastmailFF` instead of `--class FastmailFF`.

Here is the complete `firefox-personal.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox (Personal)
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Browse the Web
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal %u
Icon=firefox
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
# NOTE: If this is not set to the same as the argument of the --name option,
# then GNOME Shell won't show the nice Firefox icon and the user facing
# "Firefox (Personal)" text along with it.
StartupWMClass=FirefoxPersonal
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Keywords=web;browser;internet;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;profile-manager-window;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal --new-window %u

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal --private-window %u
```

Comment: I get "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile."

Comment: Thanks for noting @EoghanM. I've updated the answer to fix the issue.